# Javascript rotator how to read VAR list of urls from text file

Tags: javascript, iframe

The code below is based on [Rotating URLs within an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137530/rotating-urls-within-an-iframe)

```
    <iframe src="http://example.com/file01.html" id="rotator"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // start when the page is loaded
    window.onload = function() {

        var urls = [
            "http://example.com/file02.html",
            "http://example.com/file03.html",
            "http://example.com/file04.html"
        ];

        var index = 1;
        var el = document.getElementById("rotator");

        setTimeout(function rotate() {

            if (index === urls.length) {
                index = 0;
            }

            el.src = urls[index];
            index = index + 1;

            // continue rotating iframes
            setTimeout(rotate, 5000);

        }, 5000); // 5000ms = 5s
    };
</script>
```

But how to modify the code to read this list of urls from a separate text file ? 
Not

```
var urls = [
    "http://example.com/file02.html",
    "http://example.com/file03.html",
    "http://example.com/file04.html"
];
```

but something like

```
var urls = /list.txt
```

as advised, tried to change the block above to something like

```
var urls = new XMLHttpRequest();
urls.open('GET', '/list.txt');
urls.onreadystatechange = function() {
  alert(urls.responseText);
}
urls.send();
```

also tried

```
var urls = new XMLHttpRequest();
urls.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (urls.readyState == 4) {
 alert(urls.responseText);
}
};
urls.open("GET", "list.txt", true);
urls.send(null);
```

But no success with both of that, iFrame crashes.
Thanks for any other ideas or hints to try

Comment: Ajax, request file or use an array and append the file to the page.

Comment: Yes, Google says the same. Now looking for the code examples to try.